# PHP: Using ob_start or another method to separate variables and propogate data

Tags: php

```
ob_start(function($c) use (&$online){
    $replacements = array(
        "online"=> $online
    );
    return preg_replace_callback("/{(\w+)}/",function($m) use ($replacements) {
        return isset($replacements[$m[1]]) ? $replacements[$m[1]] : $m[0];
    },$c);
});
```

The above ob_start() code is a function I got several years ago.  I am trying to figure out either how to modify it to achieve a goal or use a different method of doing this.

I have an editor that I want users to be able to type  `{%data_1%}` and it echo out `<?php $data['data_1']; ?>` when ob_start() or another method gets it.  And if the `_1` is changed to `_2` it will echo out `<?php echo $data['data_2']`.  I know I can add each one in there, but I was hoping there was a way I could set up 1 thing and it automatically does it where `{%data_#%} = <?php echo $data['data_#']; ?>`

### EDIT

I don't want predefined for each one. The data items go between 1 and 20, and I don't want to include that in the code because I may in end increasing that in the future etc. so what I want is to have `{%data_*%}` where it changes the line of code to `<?php echo $data['data_*]; ?>` and places the number in the * place into the replaced code. Each one will automatically generate that code and the number will be replaced. I need it to do this, because I want to do other things with ob_start too similar. I'm gonna end up having a decent list of items being replaced and I don't want to manage a list

gonna do the same with menu... `{%menu_#%}` is going to be replaced with `<?php echo menu($_data['data_#']) ?>` So the output code needs to be able to be changed..but it needs to automically recognize the # and grab it. Not even sure if this is really possible.

if possible, it needs to get the first thing (data/menu) and use the _ as a seperator, and get the number followed (1-20 for now), and basically propogate new code. If first thing is data -> insert `<?php echo data['data_#']; ?>` and if the first thing is menu, insert `<?php echo menu($_data['data_#']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over the past few days, I found that using ob_start() to return php code can only be done via eval() and that it is somewhat of an unsafe code as it leaves you open to php injections.  So, I have transitioned over and learned how to code a template engine and used a .tpl file so that users cannot put their own php code into the page and everything gets processed using a php page running in the background using functions.  This prevented me from having to use an eval() code as it was recommended by another SO user that I stick away from using.

So since I can't delete this question because it has an answer, I wanted to inform everyone who viewed this question what I learned and would suggest working with template engines & functions and avoid using the method I am recommending in my question.

Thank you @Mohammad Reza for working with me on a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to do?

```
<?php
$data = array("data_1" => "Data Number 1", "data_2" => "Data Number 2");
ob_start(function($buffer) use (&$data){    
            $pattern = "/{%(data_.*?)%}/";
            preg_match_all($pattern, $buffer, $output);
            $return = "";
            foreach($output[1] as $dataitem){
                 $return .= $data[$dataitem]."\n";
            }
            return $return;
        });
?>
{%data_1%}
{%data_2%}
<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

**Based on the following comments, this is the second version of what I think you want to do:**

```
<?php
ob_start(function($buffer){ 
            $buffer = preg_replace("/{%(data_.*?)%}/", '<?php echo $data[\'$1\']; ?>', $buffer);
            $buffer = preg_replace("/{%menu_#(.*?)%}/", '<?php echo menu($_data[\'data_$1\']); ?>', $buffer);
            return $buffer;
        });
?>
{%data_1%}
{%menu_#2%}
{%data_2%}
<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work at all.  When I put this code on the page, it breaks the page.  Also, it doesn't change when I put `{%data_1%}` to `<?php echo $data['data_1']; ?>`   I also don't want to have to enter each one.  I want it to automatically work if possible.  If {%data_*%} then it changes it to the other.  If there is another method besides ob_start that can do this, then I am open for suggestions.  Basically I'm making an editor and I want to allow certain short code entries and the page code will do the rest.

Comment: This means I didn't understand what you want at all :)

Comment: Can you explain everything once again in a way that I can understand? Because the code that I wrote automatically looks at the buffer between ob_start and ob_end_flush, finds any {%data_*%} and loads its value from the predefined array ($data).

Comment: I don't want predefined for each one. The data items go between 1 and 20, and I don't want to include that in the code because I may in end increasing that in the future etc.  so what I want is to have {%data_*%} where it changes the line of code to <?php echo $data['data_*]; ?> and places the number in the * place into the replaced code. Each one will automatically generate that code and the number will be replaced.  I need it to do this, because I want to do other things with ob_start too similar. I'm gonna end up having a decent list of items being replaced and I don't want to manage a list

Comment: gonna do the same with menu... {%menu_#%} is going to be replaced with <?php echo menu($_data['data_#']) ?>  So the output code needs to be able to be changed..but it needs to automically recognize the # and grab it.  Not even sure if this is really possible.

Comment: if possible, it needs to get the first thing (data/menu) and use the _ as a seperator, and get the number followed (1-20 for now), and basically propogate new code.  If first thing is data -> insert <?php echo data['data_#']; ?> and if the first thing is menu, insert <?php echo menu($_data['data_#']

Comment: Alright. Check the edited code section. I hope this is what you're looking for (I re-edited it a few minutes ago).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44122/discussion-between-mohammad-reza-and-kdjernigan)